# Azure WebJob sporadically fails with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: azure, out-of-memory, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to figure out the reason why an Azure WebJob sporadically fails with OutOfMemoryException.

There are 3 App Services assigned to the same Standard 3 App Service plan (4 cores, 7GB RAM). One of them consists of a set of static HTML, CSS and JS files. Another App service is an ASP.NET MVC application. The last one is a set of WebJobs (1 continuous and 3 triggered).

One of the triggered WebJobs is an import which runs at night when there are no traffic from the users. Some times the import fails with an OutOfMemoryException. According to the Azure Metrics graphics, RAM utilization of the Service Plan is never bigger than 50% with an average value of about 40%. The App Service with the job uses up to 1.3 GB of RAM.

My question is how is it possible that OutOfMemoryException occurs, but there is no respective evidence of critical RAM usage on the graphics?

Comment: we will need to dig into our log.   Mind sharing the site name here or indirectly (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) as well as the triggered webjob name.

Comment: @SuwatCh, unfortunately I am not in a position to disclose this information publicly due to security policy. Is there any other way I can share it with you directly?

Comment: @andrey: that's why Suwat suggested the 'indirect' method. Please see his link.

Comment: Did you have any luck @AndreyC? We're experiencing the same issues in our production Azure environment.